# How to check which resource is making webpage load slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome-devtools, html

One webpage is loading slowly, it's basically because of some javascript which is making loading of the page slow. I understand that, if there is any synchronous code which is taking time to load, then it can make the load time slow.

My question is, how do I investigate which script is making this happen. I'm familiar with chrome network debugger but exactly not sure how to find out this script. If I can find out the JS file, how do I check which piece of the code in the file is making it slow?

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to check the resources on your page with the actions performed while loading, open developer tools on Google Chrome(F12) and go to Performance Tab>> Click Record and reload the page, stop it and see the breakdown time wise.

You can go onto Audits tab and start a new audit to see detailed performance of your page.

Alternatively, you can use Google Pagespeed to test and also to get the compressed resources to speed up your webpage : https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

or use GTmetrix to choose the location and test your page : https://gtmetrix.com

In GTmetrix, it will help you identify the time taken by each resource on your page(js,css,images) so that you can find and fix it. It also provides useful info to fix those.

Click on Waterfall tab to see the time taken for each file/resource .

Comment: thanks, how do I check which code snippet in the javascript file is taking time to load? because the JS file has many individual code blocks and some of them are requesting 3rd party resources also.

Comment: The best way to find the exact code snippet or function which is taking more execution time inside a js file is to use javascript timers or you can use Chrome devTool methods like console.time() and console.timeEnd().

Comment: const iterations = 1000;
console.time('Function 1');
for(const i=0; i < iterations; i++){
    funtionOne();
}
console.timeEnd('Function 1);

console.time('Function 2);
while(const i=0; i< iterations; i++){
    functionTwo();
}
console.timeEnd('Function 2');

Comment: thanks, but how do we investigate that if we don't have access to the website code. How to find it out from chrome dev tools end (rather than opening the specific js file from the webserver)

Comment: apparently one bigger js file is taking more time, and it has calls to several other js files, so in the network debugger when I sort by time, I was able to see all those js files (the which were called from the main file).

Comment: you can grab the js file from the resources and test the code after filtering using gtmetrix. You can run individual snippet time tests using jsben.ch or jsperf.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160371/discussion-between-sainath-and-coderakki).